# Ask user to input desired mathematical operation

Tags: c, switch-statement

I am trying to write a C program where user will input their desired mathematical operation.  I am able to do it but can't figure out **how to execute the operation on two different numbers as the operation** I stored in a `char` type variable called `operation`.

> How I can solve this?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main(){

    char operation;
    int num1;
    int num2;

    printf("enter an expression \n");
    scanf("%c",&operation);
    printf("enter num1 \n");
    scanf("%d",&num1);
    printf("enter num2 \n");
    scanf("%d",&num2);

    printf("entered  expression is =");
    printf("%d%c%d \n",num1,operation,num2);

    printf("result is \n");

    // Here i had to put the - sign to ensure a subtraction, I want it to be automatic
    printf("%d%c%d = %d",num1,operation,num2,num1-num2); 

}
```

Comment: Use `if else if` ladders or `switch-case` for each operation.

Answer (score 2):

What you need here, is a `switch` statement.

For every operation, you need to add a different `case` to perform that operation. Something like

```
switch(operation)
{
  case '+':
               //perform addition, num1+num2
  case '-':
               //perform subtraction, num1-num2
  case '*':
               //perform multiplication, num1*num2
  case '/':
               //perform division, num1/num2
}
```

Comment: ok,, i thought if i could made the operation automatic it would be better ..thanks anyway :)

Comment: @AL-zami Well, this is _automatic_. :)

Comment: if(operation==" * ") gives me an error saying """comparison between pointer and integer ,double by default """

Comment: @AL-zami why did you use `""`, see the snippet in my answer, use `''`.

Comment: i am actually form javascript background mostly..this type of issues is pretty new to me,,, why double quote shouldn't work ?

Comment: @AL-zami _double quote_ denotes a string, whereas the single quote is an _int_ value.

Comment: ok ,,but my operation variable is not a int value,it is a char value,,i mean a single character string,,so double quote should work as you said it is for string ,,i am comparing a string to another string here ,,isn't it ??

Comment: @AL-zami there is nothing called _single character string_. Though you're using a `char` data type, you'll compare the `int` values.

Comment: @AL-zami  A `char` is an integer.  `int` is an integer.  Comparing integers makes sense.  `"+"` and `"xyz"` are strings: arrays of `char` with a terminating null character.  Comparing arrays to integer is _rarely_ correct,

Comment: @AL-zami if the *automatic* way you are thinking of is something like `eval`, it isn't supported by C, mainly because it's a compiled language and `eval` requires that the instruction is evaluated at run-time, which can't be done.